# How can I add forward class references used in the -Swift.h header?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm integrating Swift code into a large Objective-C project, but I'm running into problems when my Swift code refers to Objective-C classes. For example, suppose I have:

1. An Objective-C class called `MyTableViewController`
2. An Objective-C class called `DeletionWorkflow`

I declared a Swift class as follows:

```
class DeletionVC: MyTableViewController {
  let deleteWorkflow: DeletionWorkflow

  ...
}
```

If I now try to use this class by importing `ProjectName-Swift.h` into Objective-C code, I get undefined symbol errors for both `MyTableViewController` and `DeletionWorkflow`.

I can fix the problem in that individual source file by importing `DeletionWorkflow.h` and `MyTableViewController.h` before I import `ProjectName-Swift.h` but this doesn't scale up to a large project where I want my Swift and Objective-C to interact often.

Is there a way to add forward class references to `ProjectName-Swift.h` so that these errors don't occur when I try to use Swift classes from Objective-C code in my app?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a little silly, but it sounds like your "workaround" is what Apple intended, at least for now. From [the interoperability guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_75):

> If you use your own Objective-C types in your Swift code, make sure to import the Objective-C headers for those types prior to importing the Swift generated header into the Objective-C `.m` file you want to access the Swift code from.

In [this devforums thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/977692#977692), someone mentioned they already filed a bug in Radar. [You probably should too.](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if they never fix this. It seems like a hard problem, not easily solved using static techniques like bridging headers. I think the only way would be to get rid of the bridging header mechanism altogether and marry the Swift and Objective-C compilers more closely together.

Answer (score 21):

You can create another header file that forward declares or imports the necessary classes, and then imports `ProjectName-Swift.h`. For example, create a file named `ProjectName-Swift-Fixed.h` with the contents:

```
// ProjectName-Swift-Fixed.h

// Forward declarations for property classes
@class DeletionWorkflow;

// Imports for superclasses
#import "MyTableViewController.h";

#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"
```

Then, instead of `#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"` in your codebase, use `#import "ProjectName-Swift-Fixed.h`.

Comment: Definitely agree this is a bug. Hopefully Apple makes this easier soon!

Comment: This is definitely the obvious solution - just create a faux umbrella header, as you do for a framework.  Yes, they could / should have done it, but it's easy enough to work around given all the other bugs that they should fix first.

Comment: had more luck with coding #import  $(SWIFT_MODULE_NAME)-Swift.h

Comment: @johnboiles THANK YOU!!! You definitely helped me a lot. I looking for a solution from two days ago.