# Unknown type name for swift property

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have a CustomViewController class written in swift and a CustomNavigationController class written in Objective C. I'm trying to add my CustomNavigationController as a property to my CustomViewController. I've added `#import "CustomNavigationController.h"` to my bridging header.

In my CustomViewController I have:

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController {

    var navController: CustomNavigationController?
...
//init methods


...


 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Set up Navigation Controller
        navController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CustomNavigationController") as CustomNavigationController!
}
```

There are no errors until I try to build and run...I get "unknown type name 'CustomNavigationController'; did you mean 'UINavigationController'?"

Does anyone know why it doesn't recognize the type?

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Comment: When declaring the property at the top. It runs if I declare navController as a UINavigationController and then downcast it to my CustomNavigationController in viewDidLoad, but I feel like that's a roundabout way of doing it.

Comment: I tried it and it works fine for me (at least based on what you've revealed so far)

Comment: Look in the build settings and make sure the Objective-C Bridging Header is pointing at your bridging header.

Comment: @matt It is...But I just realized that I don't need this to be a property anyway so I just declared it in viewDidLoad. The error still doesn't make sense though

Comment: In my test, I put the `var navController: CustomNavigationController?` line in as many different places as I could think of and there was no error.

Comment: It might have something to do with me trying to instantiate it from the storyboard, but thats just a shot in the dark

Comment: @matt: Here's an example project demonstrating the bug https://johnboiles.s3.amazonaws.com/SharedOnline/MyProject.zip

Comment: @johnboiles That's a great example. Couldn't be simpler! Thanks very much. You might like to put that on github where it's easier for people to see and play with.

Comment: @johnboiles The real question is why I can't reproduce this in my own very simple test. Is it because I'm using a storyboard and you're not?

Comment: @johnboiles Nope, it's not the storyboard. I deleted the storyboard and I still compile just fine. I don't see any difference between your project and mine, but there must be one...!

Comment: @johnboiles I got it! Delete the `#import` of the bridging header from the app delegate class file and your project compiles just fine.

Comment: Okay, I've summed up my conclusions in a new answer.

Comment: @matt if you don't import `MyProject-Swift.h` you won't be able to use the Swift class (MyClass in the example) in Objective-C code. I'll update the example to make that more explicit.

Comment: Here's a more explicit version of the example project demonstrating the bug. It now explicitly uses the Swift class from Objective-C. https://johnboiles.s3.amazonaws.com/SharedOnline/MyProject2.zip

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your Objective-C code, you are somewhere importing the automatically generated `-Swift.h` header. In that same code, *before* that `#import` line, insert `#import "CustomNavigationController.h"`. The order of these two `#import` statements is crucial!

This will solve the problem by making sure that CustomNavigationController is in the namespace before the automatically generated `-Swift.h` header, and so the latter will know about the former and all will be well.

This is something of an annoyance if that Objective-C class had no need to know about CustomNavigationController, but it solves the problem going forward and allows you to continue to work with your hybrid project.

Comment: As @johnboiles has pointed out, this is actually in the [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_75).

Comment: This is pointed out in the answer, but make sure you check each of the files where you have `#import X-Swift.h`.

Comment: I did this, going through each OBJC file where I use Swift classes and setting my `-Swift.h` file as the last include, but it still failed with the same error :(

Answer (score 8):

Looks like the `ProjectName-Swift.h` generated header file doesn't automatically include the contents of `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h`. This causes any types that haven't already been declared before importing `ProjectName-Swift.h` to throw the `Unknown type name` error in the compiler. This seems like a bug.

My workaround was to create an alternate version of `ProjectName-Swift.h` that forward declares the classes that are causing the errors, then imports `ProjectName-Swifth.h`. I called it `ProjectName-Swift-Fixed.h`. For me, `ProjectName-Swift-Fixed.h` looked like this:

```
// ProjectName-Swift-Fixed.h
@class CustomViewController;
#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"
```

Then, everywhere in code where I had `#include "ProjectName-Swift.h"`, I replaced it with `#include "ProjectName-Swift-Fixed.h"`

Comment: Found another [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24132572/163827) that found a small mention of this in [Apple's ObjC - Swift Interop Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_75): "If you use your own Objective-C types in your Swift code, make sure to import the Objective-C headers for those types prior to importing the Swift generated header into the Objective-C .m file you want to access the Swift code from."

Comment: Your demo project had a bug in it (yours, not Apple's), which I eventually found. See my new answer.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the issue here. This only happens if you are both using Swift classes in Objective-C code and Objective-C classes in your Swift code. `ProjectName-Swift.h`, the file that tells your Objective-C code about your Swift classes, will reference the Objective-C classes that are used in Swift code. If those classes haven't already been imported, or forward-declared, the compiler will error.

Comment: Okay, I see. But the requirement that you import those classes first is pretty minimal and is certainly a lot easier than your workaround. For example, in your http://johnboiles.s3.amazonaws.com/SharedOnline/MyProject2.zip example, in the app delegate just say `#import "CustomViewController.h"` before you say `#import "MyProject-Swift.h"` and the problem is solved. That's a lot less onerous than your song-and-dance above...

Comment: That's certainly a fine solution for projects that only `#import "MyProject-Swift.h"` once or twice. If you `#import "MyProject-Swift.h"` in more than a few places, it becomes time consuming to update your `#import`s above every place you `#import "MyProject-Swift.h"`. I prefer to do all the necessary forward declarations and and/or imports for the Swift header in one place.

Answer (score 5):

In case you can´t fix the problem by changing the order of `#import` statements as suggested by the above answers, checking the files in your `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h` for missing framework imports might work.

In my case, I had a class in the bridging header file that was using `UIImage` in one of it´s methods. When my project consisted solely of Objective-C that worked fine but when exposing this header to Swift I had to add `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` in order to remove the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
navController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CustomNavigationController") as? CustomNavigationController
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same situation. In my case, the errors resolved after updating swift version to 3.0 in **all targets** by Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax. Hope it helps