# Swift compiling bug "Unknown type name" and "Expected a type"

Tags: ios, swift

I'm running into an issue where my Swift code compiles fine but then the generated -Swift.h file has an error in it...

Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
class MyScene : CCLayer {
    var ctrl : CCControlSlider?
}
```

This compiles just fine in the swift code and I can see the methods on the ctrl object just fine as well. I have the following in my bridge header:

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "CCControlSlider.h"
```

This works perfectly fine in other classes that use other libraries which work correctly.  Also note that I can use this CCControlSlider class in my objective-c classes with no issues at all as well.

Here is what happens on the generated -Swift.h file:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC15MyProject10MyScene")
@interface MyScene : CCLayer
@property (nonatomic) CCControlSlider * ctrl;
@end
```

The property has the error "Unknown type name "CCControlSlider" and if it's used in a method then it gives the error "Expected a type".

This works just fine using other classes but for some reason this one class gives this compiler error only in the generated header file and only when used from Swift.

I guess what I'm wondering is, am I doing something wrong or is this just a bug??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer given here is the simplest approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24216718/341994

Basically, somewhere in your Objective-C code you are importing the automatically generated `-Swift.h` header. In that same code, *before* that `#import` line, insert `#import "CCControlSlider.h"`. The order of these two `#import` statements is crucial!

The fact that this Objective-C class may not need CCControlSlider is irrelevant (though if it does, that's a bonus). The important thing is the order. We want to expose the namespace to CCControlSlider before exposing the namespace to the automatically generated `-Swift.h` header.

Comment: Does that make this a bug? I'd expect that the autogenerated -Swift file would have access to everything in the bridging header?

Comment: ProjectName-Swift.h file is generated by XCode automatically, you just need to import it in .m file: #import <ProjectName-Swift.h> Of course, -Swift.h file and -Bridging-Header.h, both are needed if you add Swift to Objective-C.

Answer (score 10):

While incorporating a set of Objective C files into my mostly Swift-based project I suddenly started getting a lot of these errors on them. Then I realized though the file had:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

It did not have:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

and once I added that line the errors started resolving. Cleaning afterwards always helps. Good luck

NOTE: With newer versions of Swift imports are much easier to type and are done like so:

```
import UIKit
```

Comment: Good one, would've never figured that out on my own that I also need  "higher" imports than the class I wanna import, too. Thanks man, saved me an hour

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to worry about the order of imports everywhere you import your `ProjectName-Swift.h` file, try this:

Create a file named `ProjectName-Swift-Fixed.h` with the following contents

```
// ProjectName-Swift-Fixed.h
@class CCControlSlider;
// (Add other imports or forward declarations here)
#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"
```

Second, throughout the rest of your codebase, replace `#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"` with `#import "ProjectName-Swift-Fixed.h"`

This approach has two benefits over copying and pasting a list of `#import` statements above each place you use Swift classes in Objective-C code:

1. You won't have to worry about the order of imports, except in the `ProjectName-Swift-Fixed.h` file
2. When you add new Objective-C classes to your Swift code, you won't have to add new `#import` statements in every Objective-C file that uses Swift code

Answer (score 1):

OC code has a global call # import "projectName - swift. H", and "the projectName - Bridging - Header. H" and calls the OC code.Is equivalent to the parent class call subclasses, subclasses and calls the superclass.To make the "projectName - Bridging - Header. H" calls the oc class don't call # import "projectName - swift. H.