# Unknown type name appear after I bridged my objective c code

Tags: objective-c, swift, mapkit, bridging-header

Issue:

Xcode complaint about Unknown type name 'MKUserLocation' in my ViewController.h after I added `#import "ViewController.h"` to my bridging header. This error will go away after I remove it from bridging header

Question:

1. what's the work around for this issue or what am I doing wrong?
2. why am I getting this error since MKUserLocation is part of Apple's MapKit?

Resource I read:

[Unknown type name for swift property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099210/unknown-type-name-for-swift-property)