# Inheritance from an Objective-c base view controller from Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, swift

I am trying to migrate a `UIViewController` Objective-C class to Swift. This view controller is inheriting from a `BaseViewController` where I have common functionality that I want to have in all controllers. The problem I am having is that the generated `myproject-Swift.h` is not able to find my `BaseViewController`.

Is there any way to implement a `UIViewController` in swift that inherits from a `BaseViewController` (subclass of `UIViewController`) written in Objective-C? Is there a bridging problem?

It can be reproduced with this minimal code:

**BaseViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BaseViewController : UIViewController 
@end
```

**BaseViewController.m**

```
import "BaseViewController.h"

@implementation BaseViewController
@end
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController : BaseViewController {

}
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "projectname-Swift.h"   // Replace with your project name

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

**projectname-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import "BaseViewController.h"
```

Comment: What does your objc bridging header look like?

Comment: @NateCook Updated. It's pretty simple.

Comment: Just having a bridging header isn't enoough, is it set up properly? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24272184/connect-objective-c-framework-to-swift-ios-8-app-parse-framework/24272431#24272431

Comment: @JackWu I think so. The header is included in "Objective-C Bridging Header".

Comment: Interesting. Looks like you have all the required parts in the right format & location. ...Maybe a dumb question, but did you actually build/run the project? That's required for the generated .swift header. Somewhere in the WWDC "Integrating With Objective-C" video there was also mention of using @class forward declaration, but I don't recall specifics off the top of my head...

Comment: I built a single-view project with all these settings and it worked fine - I could even declare a property in "BaseViewController.h" and access it in the subclass. Maybe a bug? Can you try recreating the project step by step?

Comment: @mc01 Yes, it's built. And yes, it seems to be related with the order on how each source file is built.

Comment: @NateCook I repeated the steps and I had the same error :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in the accepted answer on [How can I add forward class references used in the -Swift.h header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098408/how-can-i-add-forward-class-references-used-in-the-swift-h-header)

[Interoperability guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_75) (Importing Swift into Objective-C):

> If you use your own Objective-C types in your Swift code, make sure to
>   import the Objective-C headers for those types prior to importing the
>   Swift generated header into the Objective-C .m file you want to access
>   the Swift code from.

The example is solved by importing `BaseViewController` before the importing `projectname-Swift.h` in:

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "BaseViewController.h"
#import "projectname-Swift.h"   // Replace with your project name
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they have fixed the issue. Currently under XCode6-Beta6 the problem reported by @atxe does not occur anymore. Therefor you can finally roll your **AppDelegate.m** header back to:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "projectname-Swift.h"   // Replace with your project name
```