# Xcode 6 Swift + Objective-C Build Issues - Unknown Types due to Import Order?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm finding it very challenging to structure a mixed Swift/Obj-C iOS application to avoid build errors after converting classes to Swift.

This is an issue relating to a very brief passage in the Swift documentation:

> If you use your own Objective-C types in your Swift code, make sure to
>   import the Objective-C headers for those types prior to importing the
>   Swift generated header into the Objective-C .m file you want to access
>   the Swift code from.

Firstly, although the documentation is quite explicit about importing the `-Swift.h` file into `.m` files, there are very often references to types from a classes now based in Swift code in the `.h` files of Obj-C classes, so I end up having to import `-Swift.h` in `.h` files most of the time. It seems odd to contradict the doc, but I don't see how else these headers would build, and this has worked most of the time so far.

The real problem occurs when the generated `-Swift.h` file itself contains compiler errors such as

> Unknown type name 'SomeObjCClass'

The only way to get past these errors seems to be to be sure that said class is reached prior to the `-Swift.h` file, as the documentation suggests, but unable to figure out how the order of the build is determined I find myself importing all kinds of Obj-C headers all over the project prior to the generated header until I get a working build. There's no way this is a good way to go about this, but I don't know the right way.

How do I determine where the `-Swift.h` header is being included for the first time so that I can get all required Obj-C classes imported just above it, and would that then be enough that just `-Swift.h` can be imported in remaining places as required, or does the collection of it's prerequisites need to be included above it every time (which I suppose is not unlike what i'm messily doing now)?

Comment: Would forward declarations help? i.e. just use `@class ObjectiveCClassYouWantToUse;` before the `-Swift.h` import that's causing you the problem? See also [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098408/how-can-i-add-forward-class-references-used-in-the-swift-h-header), which I think is pretty much a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience so far in order to use Objective-C classes in Swift I just included those .h files in my `-Bridging-Header.h` and for Swift classes that need to be used in Objective-C code I include `-Swift.h` in those .m files.

I haven't had any issues with this unknown type. And all my references to Swift classes are contained in the .m files. But if there is a Swift class you need to reference in a .h file, then you should just do a forward declaration `@class MySwiftClass`.