# Swift build error (involving word "class" as argument) with subclassed Objective-C class

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a build error when trying to subclass a custom Objective-C class (a subclass of UIViewController) in Swift.

When I try to subclass in Swift, I get the build errors in the picture below. All of them relate to the use of the word `class` as an argument in the [OCMapper](https://github.com/aryaxt/OCMapper) library (where I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/aryaxt/OCMapper/issues/25) as well).

Some more notes:

- In the project, I both import and use Objective-C code in the Swift code and import and use Swift code in the Objective-C code.
- I import the compiled `Module-Swift.h` only in `.m` and `.mm` files and forward declare classes that I need in `.h` files.
- I've attempted to create a `Module-Swift-Fixed.h` class where I forward declare and/or import the custom Objective-C class headers (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098408/how-can-i-add-forward-class-references-used-in-the-swift-h-header/24132572#24132572)), but that hasn't made a difference.

[image: many build errors]
[image: build error]

Has anyone seen anything like this before or have a solution?

Comment: Before subclassing, everything compiles okay in the Objective-C?

Comment: Can you show the sub-class source?

Answer (score 1):

I have as yet not been able to trace where in the language spec this is documented, but I suspect you have come across the same problem that I recently faced in objective-c since moving to Xcode 6.4.

I had a message (method) defined as follows

```
- (BOOL)canProcessClass:(Class) class {
    return [class isSubclassOfClass:[NSSet class]];
}
```

with the same compile error as you mentioned `Expected identifier`. The fix was simple - just rename the the `class` argument to something like `classToProcess`. Which would give you the following

```
- (BOOL)canProcessClass:(Class) classToProcess {
    return [classToProcess isSubclassOfClass:[NSSet classToProcess]];
}
```

Hence just rename the arguments in your Swift code to not use the (key)word `class` and you should be fine.

If anyone can point me to the language spec that documents this I would really appreciate it. As far as I'm aware you shouldn't use `Class`, but I haven't able to find anything about `class` except the obvious that it is a message (method) available on classes.