# Using an Objective-C file in Swift project. Importing the header file in the bridging header causes the `#import "Module-Swift.h"` to fail

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I have one Obj-C class (one .h, one .m) in my project and about seven Swift files. When I use `#import "Class.h"` in the bridging header, it causes Xcode to lose the `#import "ModuleName-Swift.h"`. If I don't import the `Class.h` header file in the bridging header, `#import "ModuleName-Swift.h"` works just fine.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using swift components in your .m file ? Cause it will be a circular reference

Comment: Sounds like you have swift reference in Class.h

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098408/how-can-i-add-forward-class-references-used-in-the-swift-h-header?

Answer (score 1):

This enforces a recursive requirement and thus won't work.