# Framework not visible in auto-generated swift file

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, objc-bridging-header

I want to import some swift classes in objective-c project.
I added all classes, I created the bridging-header, I imported the MyTarget-swift.h file in my classes and everything seems working fine.

When I'm building the project, I found a very strange error on generated swift.h file:

[image]

StoreKit framework is already added to project. I have no idea what is going on.
Anybody has any idea?

Comment: Clean your project and try again. I sometimes get these weird errors because of stale build data. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: This not solve my problem. I already tried billion times. Also Analyze. Delete derivered data. Nothing works

Answer (score 2):

The right answer is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24195188/4563329

That helped me to fix my problem. I will post my fixed file here:

I created another header file in objective-c named `ModuleTargetName-Swift-Fixed.h`
Inside of it first I imported `StoreKit` and after I imported `ModuleTargetName-Swift.h`. In my objective-c classes I imported `ModuleTargetName-Swift-Fixed.h`

This is my class:

```
// Forward declarations for property classes
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

// Imports for superclasses
#import "ModuleTargetName-Swift.h"
```